# Working efficiently with single-registry in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a system in which I **read and write several times a single registry using PHP**, and which disappear after a while (several minutes).

Basically, kind of a voting system with a counter (just an integer) which can increase and decrease (by a factor of 1).

Therefore, I must read it every time the user visit this page and write on it most of the times (when the user interacts).

Currently, I am doing it using a DB (MySQL), with a single table and a single registry with one column.

But I see it quite inefficient.

And I am afraid that if the website continues growing, this will collapse it, since the rest of the content can be cached, but this can't, as it should be real time.

I have thought of using a file, but it may be even worse, right?

I am hosted in a shared service, and.., therefore, **I can't use MemCached or Redis**.

**Any ideas of how to do it efficiently?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you feel what you are doing is inefficient?  Can you use more detail to describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What kind of volume are we talking about here? And what's the ratio of reads to writes?

Comment: Show some code...  simple r/w to a database table with one or few registry entries should be very fast.

Comment: What other storage does your hosting company support ???

Comment: We are talking about 1 to 20 hits per second right now.
But if it continues growing, my tests shows that it won't be allowed by the server.

I have done some tests in local, and using MemCached it is speeded up several times.

That why I am looking for a different solution, because MemCached doesn't work on it.
I have everything cached except for this, and I don't see how to do it more efficiently.

As far as I know my hosting company (Dreamhost) only supports MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I fear that in a shared hosting environment, this will be difficult. You probably can't access `/dev/shm`, so file caching is not an option. APC and memcached also don't work.

So there is only one option left: Optimizing your query. For one, I would suggest that you only use `INSERT` on one table where you write very much. Then, make a second table which only holds aggregated values. Here you need `UPDATE` but the update frequency should be on a minute or 2-minute basis (also deleting the raw data from table 1). So your data would still be near-realtime but the performance is way better plus it scales directly with an increase in the update times.